# TableLayout - where is my grid?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have just started work with Android Studio 2.2.3. I picked `TableLayout` and everything looks fine, but I cant drag and drop anything on this layout except `TableRow`. Even the grid doesn`t show up. Has anybody had the same issue?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear what exactly you want to implement, if you want to implement grid view then instead of taking table layout take recycler view and implement it as a grid view. to know more about thie follow this link  http://www.android-examples.com/android-recyclerview-with-gridview-gridlayoutmanager/

Answer (score 0):

I think you are TableLayout as root layout with these properties:  android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

So it will occupies you entire Activity. It allows only TableRow because it is child layout for TableLayout.

Try to change the properties as following or change the TableLayout from Root layout and later add the views to layout.

android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: "match_parent" option suits me, but I have tried with different properties as u said and I am still unable to drop anything but 'TableRow'. Do you mean it is not even possible? It worked couple months ago. I haven`t read anything about changes like that. I am confused.

Comment: Can you please ping your xml file if possible.

Comment: TableLayout accept only TableRow. You can do one thing add TableRow, add item under that TableRow. That is only alternative. Other you need change the TableLayout as RootLayout.